# validation errors on validating xhtml11-model-1.xsd

Tags: xml, eclipse, validation, xsd

On generating XML files, I use xsd-files defined by OMG. Validating over the internet takes much too long. So, I downloaded all those files for local validation. This works for the simple cases. But on going forward, more complex structures must be validated. This includes validating xhtml-structures. Most of the xsd-files downloaded from http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA have validation errors. On trying to solve them I concentrated on the file xhtml11-model-1.xsd to start, because this file contains a lot of basic definitions used by other xsd-files. The initial download file showed 71 validation errors! The downloaded file has no target name space declared, hence I added the declaration. Doing so reduced the amount of errors to 4. But at this point I got stuck. I simply have not found any mean to correct the remaining errors. I picked out one of those to analyze it as isolated case. See code below. The declaration of attributeGroup name=”xhtml.dir.attrib” can be found within the file xhtml-bdo-1.xsd. But this file neither pass validation, hence I copied the declaration into my test file for having all in one place. But on validating this simple case with eclipse Kepler, I get the error below on the ref to xhtml.dir.attrib:

```
<xs:attributeGroup ref="xhtml.dir.attrib" />
s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'xhtml.I18n.extra.attrib' must match (annotation?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)). A problem was found starting at: attributeGroup.
```

What is wrong? Why a reference declares an error when the declaration shows to be correct. Is this a problem of the eclipse validator? My misunderstanding? Should I simply ignore these validation errors? Why xsd files downloaded from w3.org do not have the targetNamespace declaration, as it seems required to validate and to use the files? 
Thanks for any hint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/datatypes/" 
xmlns:xh11d="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/datatypes/" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" >

<xs:attributeGroup name="xhtml.dir.attrib">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            "dir" Attribute from Bi Directional Text (bdo) Module
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="dir">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
                <xs:enumeration value="ltr" />
                <xs:enumeration value="rtl" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:attributeGroup>

<xs:attributeGroup name="xhtml.I18n.extra.attrib">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Extended I18n attribute</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="xhtml.dir.attrib" />
    <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xh11d:LanguageCode" />
</xs:attributeGroup>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the particular snippet you've provided, the validation errors go away if you simply ensure that there is a default namespace that matches your targetNamespace (I've just explained this in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660494/exception-src-resolve-4-2-error-resolving-component-in-xsd/19661816#19661816) here on SO) and you make the namespace aliased with "xh11d" available to your XSD processor (somehow, either through a catalog, or through a direct `xs:import`).

I would say you should not ignore validation errors, at least not until you can make an informed decision.

I'll download the XSDs and I'll have a look myself; if something worthwhile comes up, I'll let you know here.

Comment: On my snippet adding the default namespace the error was gone. So far the hint is correct. The modification is: 

    <xs:schema 
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
 xmlns:xh11d="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/datatypes/" 
 elementFormDefault="qualified">
 
 <xs:import
        namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/datatypes/"
        schemaLocation="xhtml-datatypes-1.xsd"/>

But this doesn't really help in the original xsd and the question is, why should I modify the xsd from the w3 site?

Comment: I suppose those files being public, have been tested thoroughly, why they work at the w3 site but not locally? Further I observed circular dependencies, which really doesn't help! How do you handle such cases?

Comment: I personally don't think that those files have been tested thoroughly. At least based on the tools available to me, which are .NET and Java based, some of the XSDs are invalid. (I am still looking into it... for e.g., I am getting a cvc-enumeration-invalid for the default value in `aria-relevant` attribute in aria-attributes-1.xsd file...) Circular dependencies are bad in terms of packaging... but it shouldn't be an issue... If you remove all the schema locations and put all files together in a schema collection manually... circular dependencies are gone, while the content is still correct...

Comment: Thanks for confirmation of my findings. I have already startet to put all those files locally, and to change the schema locations accordingly. It's a laborious and boring work. I hate inutil work, so it's important to me, to hear from a third party, not being wrong.