# Exception: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I am tyring to validate a xml against a xsd. The following is the xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" targetNamespace="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx" xmlns:cl="http://www.xxxxxx/contactlist" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:complexType name="contactNumberType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="contactNumbersType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="contact_number" type="contactNumberType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="contactType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="company" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="jobtitle" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="emailadress" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="addresses" type="addressesType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="contact_numbers" type="contactNumbersType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="addressType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="street_address1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="street_address2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="suburb" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="postcode" type="xsd:integer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="contacts">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="contact" type="contactType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="addressesType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="address" type="addressType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

I am getting the following exception. Please help me understand what is that I am missing

Exception: src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'contactNumberType'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the authoring approach, you have to make sure that the default namespace (xmlns attribute's value) matches the targetNamespace attribute's value.

When you reference a type, attribute, attributeGroup, element or group by name, that name is a qualified name. If the name you reference is without a prefix, then it is assumed to be in the default namespace, if specified, or no namespace at all. Having a default namespace of `http://www.w3schools.com`, the processor is looking for {http://www.w3schools.com}contactNumberType; your XSD defines a {http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx}contactNumberType, which obviously don't match. Fixing the default namespace, fixes your reference.

`xmlns="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx" targetNamespace="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx"`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have new problem. My xsd is <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com.au/contactlist" 
 xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com.au/contactlist" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified"> and xml is <contacts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com.au/contactlist"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mycompany.com.au/contactlist XML_Assignment1.xsd">. Now the error is Exception: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'contacts'

Comment: I found and fixed the problem as well my xsd is missing the xsd:element specification. All the elements are mentiioned as complexType but no actual element. Thanks for the help